# Alternative to looping? Vectorisation, cython?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, cython

I have a pandas dataframe something like the below:

```
       Total    Yr_to_Use   First_Year_Del    Del_rate 2019 2020 2021 2022 2023 etc 
ref1    100       2020         5                 10    0    0    0    0   0
ref2    20        2028         2                 5     0    0    0    0   0 
ref3    30        2021         7                 16    0    0    0    0   0
ref4    40        2025         9                 18    0    0    0    0   0
ref5    10        2022         4                 30    0    0    0    0   0
```

The 'Total' column shows how many of a product needs to be delivered. 
'First_yr_Del' tells you how many will be delivered in the first year. After this the delivery rate reverts to 'Del_rate' - a flat rate that can be applied each year until all products are delivered.
The 'Year to Use' column tells you the first year column to begin delivery from.

**EXAMPLE:** Ref1 has 100 to deliver. It will start delivering in 2020 and will deliver 5 in the first year, and 10 each year after that until all 100 are accounted for.

Any ideas how to go about this?

I thought i might use something like the below to reference which columns to use in turn, but i'm not even sure if that's helpful or not as it will depend on the solution (in the proper version, base_date.year is defined as the first column in the table - 2019):

```
start_index_for_slice = df.columns.get_loc(base_date.year)
end_index_for_slice = start_index_for_slice+no_yrs_to_project
df.columns[start_index_for_slice:end_index_for_slice]
```

I'm pretty new to python and aren't sure if i'm getting ahead of myself a bit...

The way i would think to go about it would be to use a for loop, or something using iterrows, but other posts seem to say this is a bad idea and i should be using vectorisation, cython or lambdas. Of those 3 i've only managed a very simple lambda so far. The others are a bit of a mystery to me since the solution seems to suggest doing one action after another until complete.

Any and all help appreciated!

Thanks

EDIT: Example expected output below (I edited some of the dates so you can better see the logic):

```
       Total    Yr_to_Use   First_Year_Del Del_rate 2019 2020 2021 2022 2023etc 
ref1    100       2020         5              10    0    5    10    10   10
ref2    20        2021         2              5     0    0    2     5    5 
ref3    30        2021         7              16    0    0    7     16   7
ref4    40        2019         9              18    9    18   13    0    0
ref5    10        2020         4              30    0    4    6     0    0
```

Comment: Can you also paste your expected output dataframe?

Comment: I've put this at the end of the original post for reference. I changed some of the dates so you could better see the expected output. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't look like it should be performance critical anyway - if I were you I'd start by writing something that works (whichever way you find easiest to think about) then see if the performance is good enough

Comment: how many rows does your `df` have?

Comment: Around 5,000 rows

Comment: ok... by the way, your input `df` does not match the output `df`, see column "Yr_to_Use"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another option, which separates the calculation of the rates/years matrix and appends it to the input `df` later on. Still does looping in the script itself (not "externalized" to some `numpy` / `pandas` function). Should be fine for 5k rows I'd guesstimate.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# def gen_df1():

# create the inital df without years/rates
df = pd.DataFrame({'Total': [100, 20, 30, 40, 10], 
                   'Yr_to_Use': [2020, 2021, 2021, 2019, 2020], 
                   'First_Year_Del': [5, 2, 7, 9, 10],
                   'Del_rate': [10, 5, 16, 18, 30]})

# get number of rates + remainder
n, r = np.divmod((df['Total']-df['First_Year_Del']), df['Del_rate'])

# get the year of the last rate considering all rows
max_year = np.max(n + r.astype(np.bool) + df['Yr_to_Use'])

# get the offsets for the start of delivery, year zero is 2019
offset = df['Yr_to_Use'] - 2019
# subtracting the year zero lets you use this as an index...

# get a year index; this determines the the columns that will be created
yrs = np.arange(2019, max_year+1)

# prepare a n*m array to hold the rates for all years, initalize with all zero
out = np.zeros((df['Total'].shape[0], yrs.shape[0]))
# n: number of rows of the df, m: number of years where rates will have to be payed

# calculate the rates for each year and insert them into the output array
for i in range(df['Total'].shape[0]):
    # concatenate: year of the first rate, all yearly rates, a final rate if there was a remainder
    if r[i]: # if rest is not zero, append it as well
        rates = np.concatenate([[df['First_Year_Del'][i]], n[i]*[df['Del_rate'][i]], [r[i]]])
    else: # rest is zero, skip it
        rates = np.concatenate([[df['First_Year_Del'][i]], n[i]*[df['Del_rate'][i]]])
    # insert the rates at the apropriate location of the output array:
    out[i, offset[i]:offset[i]+rates.shape[0]] = rates

# add the years/rates matrix to the original df    
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(out, columns=yrs.astype(str))], axis=1, sort=False)
```

Comment: Wanted to say thanks for this - took me an embarrassing amount of time to unpick to figure out what it was doing, but learned alot by doing it. I was trying to figure out the loop and think i got part way there, got lost by 'out[i, offset[i]:offset[i]+rates.shape[0]] = rates' though - could you walk me though at all?

Comment: @GlassShark1: you're welcome! I've added some comments, hope they clarify a bit what's going on. I think the important stuff is going on *before* the actual loop; esp. the `yrs` variable which is basically an index telling you where to insert the calculated rates into the output array. `out[i, offset[i]:offset[i]+rates.shape[0]] = rates` then inserts the rates calculated for row `i` into the appropriate columns determined by the index slice `offset[i]:offset[i]+rates.shape[0]`. Let me know if that helps you.

Comment: It does. Thanks so much. All was well until i put it into my actual code. Now getting - ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (6) into shape (0) for one row. It's a row of 6 values - if i call .shape on rates i get (6,), out.shape = (5,117,26). Not sure where to start to fix it - any ideas?

Comment: @GlassShark1: sorry for the late answer! I think this error is due to a rest of zero. I' ve added a check for that, see the edited code. Hope that helps!

Comment: Just been trying to do exactly this! Will check it later. Thanks so much again - my first real python project and it's proven challenging. You've been a great help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using two user-defined function and `apply` method

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': ['ref1','ref2','ref3','ref4','ref5'], 
                        'Total': [100, 20, 30, 40, 10],
                        'Yr_to_Use': [2020, 2028, 2021, 2025, 2022],
                        'First_Year_Del': [5,2,7,9,4],
                        'Del_rate':[10,5,16,18,30]})

def f(r):
    ''' 
    Computes values per year and respective year
    '''

    n = (r['Total'] - r['First_Year_Del'])//r['Del_rate']
    leftover = (r['Total'] - r['First_Year_Del'])%r['Del_rate']
    r['values'] = [r['First_Year_Del']] + [r['Del_rate'] for _ in range(n)] + [leftover]
    r['years'] = np.arange(r['Yr_to_Use'], r['Yr_to_Use'] + len(r['values']))

    return r

df = df.apply(f, axis=1)


def get_year_range(r):
    '''
    Computes min and max year for each row
    '''

    r['y_min'] = min(r['years'])
    r['y_max'] = max(r['years'])
    return r 

df = df.apply(get_year_range, axis=1)

y_min = df['y_min'].min()
y_max = df['y_max'].max()

#Initialize each year value to zero
for year in range(y_min, y_max+1):
    df[year] = 0


def expand(r):
    '''
    Update value for each year
    '''
    for v, y in zip(r['values'], r['years']):
        r[y] = v 
    return r

# Apply and drop temporary columns
df = df.apply(expand, axis=1).drop(['values', 'years', 'y_min', 'y_max'], axis=1)
```

Comment: that gives me a `KeyError: ('l', 'occurred at index 0')`. Also, the max. year 2050 seems a bit arbitrary.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change a variable name when posting the answer, edited now! Regarding the max year, I did not understand if you already have year columns or not, you can change it dynamically

Comment: @MrFuppes I just added the function to find the min and max years that need to be computed

Comment: still should be `for v, y in zip(r['values'], r['years'])` I think

Comment: Yes thank you, I am so lazy that I use single letter column names to test :|